# Configure generated comment of overrided method

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there a way, how to change generated comment of overrided method from
'// ${todo} Auto-generated method stub' to another text only for one method.

I need show warning and tips if someone override method.

Say example:

```
public class DateHolder{
    public Date date;

    @SomeOverridingAnnotation(generateComment= "WARNING: if override and not use super then add 1 month to result!")
    public int getMonth(){
        return date.getMonth() + 1;
    }
}

public class DateHolder2 extends DateHolder{
    @Override
    public int getMonth() {
        // WARNING: if override and not use super then add 1 month to result!
        return super.getMonth();
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like an XY Problem to me.

Answer (score -1):

That's highly depends on what editor are you using, as generated comments are produced by those. Does your editor or IDE support scripted comments generator that has an access to content of your classes?

If not so. And I doubt there is one such editor. May there is another way how to reach what you want. You can manage it in your own class as so for instance:

```
public class DateHolder {
public Date date;

private int dummyInt = -42;

/**
 * Will try to call override method getMonthPlusOne, if there is not such override, then it returns month from date + 1.
 */
public final int getMonth() {
    int res = getMonthPlusOne();
    if ( res == dummyInt )
        return date.getMonth() + 1;
    return res;
}

protected int getMonthPlusOne() {
    return dummyInt;
}
```

}

```
public class DateHolder2 extends DateHolder {
    @Override
    protected int getMonthPlusOne() {
        // it will return dummyInt from DateHolder and that will add 1 to month
        return super.getMonthPlusOne();
    }
}
```

Comment: I know that, but don't want it. I'm looking for good Eclipse Plugin, that allow it (code template)

Comment: But if you find one you have to distribute it with the code. While the solution in the class is applicable in multiple editors.

Comment: You wrote normal java solution. I want eclipse solution (Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Cody Style -> Code Templates -> Code - Method body... Probably some expression write there, which will react to some method style. Maybye Custom annotation. Maybye Plugin CommentTemplate, Java coded templates